# How to transform nested strings in array to separated words?

Tags: python, arrays, string

I'm trying to do a simple array & string transformation with Python yet I'm stuck. I have this array :

```
data = ['one, two, three',  'apple, pineapple',  'frog, rabbit, dog, cat, horse']
```

And I would like to arrive to this result :

```
new_data = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'apple', 'pineapple', 'frog', 'rabbit', 'dog', 'cat', 'horse']
```

---

This is what I'm doing but whenever I use

```
data_to_string = ''.join(data) 
new_data = re.findall(r"[\w']+", data_to_string)
```

it gives me this :

```
['one', 'two', 'threeapple', 'pineapplefrog', 'rabbit', 'dog', 'cat', 'horse']
```

As you can see "threeapple" and "pineapplefrog" aren't separated, how can I avoid this issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into list comprehensions, they're great.

Here's your answer:

```
[word for string in data for word in string.split(", ")]
```

Comment: I'll check for list comprehensions then :)

Answer (score 2):

How about some simple list comprehension and string methods? `re` is overkill for this.

```
>>> data = ['one, two, three',  'apple, pineapple',  'frog, rabbit, dog, cat, horse']
>>> [word.strip() for string in data for word in string.split(',')]
['one', 'two', 'three', 'apple', 'pineapple', 'frog', 'rabbit', 'dog', 'cat', 'horse']
```

Answer (score 1):

use join and split

```
','.join(data).split(',')
```

results in

```
['one',
 ' two',
 ' three',
 'apple',
 ' pineapple',
 'frog',
 ' rabbit',
 ' dog',
 ' cat',
 ' horse']
```

Comment: Other answers are correct as well. but if you have large array like data*10, then you get performance benefits join and split commands. % timeit ','.join(data*10).split(',')  100000 loops, best of 3: 10.3 µs per loop  %timeit [word.strip() for string in data*10 for word in string.split(',')] 10000 loops, best of 3: 42.4 µs per loop. not a big deal, but thought to share.